# Unexpected null elements in output array

Tags: json, jolt

**EDIT: Now after 16 hours break I realized I have been misreading the results for hours - I didn't notice that there is `null` in all cases, so the behavior is consistent unlike I claim in this question (facepalm). However I decided not to delete this question but only close it as there is already useful answers.**

Consider the following input JSON:

```json
{
  "widgets": [
    {
      "type": "FOO",
      "id": "F1"
    },
    {
      "type": "ZAP",
      "id": "Z1"
    },
    {
      "type": "BAR",
      "id": "B1"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following transformation:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "FOO": {
              "@(2,id)": "widgets[&3].fooId"
            },
            "BAR": {
              "@(2,id)": "widgets[&3].barId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

creates the expected (correct) output. **EDIT I misread this output - I didn't realize there is 3 elements where one element is null but I though there is only 2 non-null elements**:

```json
{
  "widgets": [
    {
      "fooId": "F1"
    },
    null,
    {
      "barId": "B1"
    }
  ]
}
```

However the following transformation creates the unexpected output:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "BAR": {
              "@(2,id)": "widgets[&3].barId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This is the actual (wrong) output:

```json
{
  "widgets": [
    null,
    null,
    {
      "barId": "B1"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the expected (correct) output:

```json
{
  "widgets": [
    {
      "barId": "B1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why sometimes there is `null` elements in the `widgets` array and sometimes there is not? How I can avoid them?

Based on the many other SO questions the following operation:

```json
{
  "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
  "spec": {
    "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
  }
}
```

should remove the `null` values, but why those are not removed in the following transformation?

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "BAR": {
              "@(2,id)": "widgets[&3].barId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]
```

I'm observing this behavior in http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first output keeps `null` as well(I don't know if it should appear in the desired output). Since the index(which is `1`) of the object having `"type": "ZAP"` stays in the middle of the indexes(`0`,`1`,`2`), but not at the end, then doesn't vanish at that level.

Btw, `squashNulls` especially no impact for the objects nested within array. Indeed, it has some bugs and documented as fixed for [version 0.1.6](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases/tag/jolt-0.1.6).

You can rather use the following spec which doesn't have square-bracketed indexes such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "FOO|BAR": {
              "@(2,id)": "&4.&1.&1Id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This spec will help you resolve this query :

1)

Actually recursivelySquashNulls will work if you keep the array in a object for eg: I kept it under test object and made it to previous one.

This spec will resolve your issue :

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "BAR": {
              "@(2,id)": "widgets[&3].barId"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "test.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "test": {
        "*": "&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the web application in http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is running old version 0.1.1 that in this case behaves a bit differently than the newer versions.

At the moment the latest version available in Maven Central seems to be 0.1.7:

- https://central.sonatype.dev/artifact/com.bazaarvoice.jolt/jolt-core/0.1.7/versions

thought the Github release page only claims latest to be 0.1.6:

- https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases/tag/jolt-0.1.6

I have the impression that the very powerful and useful Jolt library is not getting all the care it deserves :(

`squashNull` seems to work ok in Java code when using version 0.1.7.

Here is my final transformation that works as expected with http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ based on answer by [Barbaros Özhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5841306/):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": "=toLower"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "type": {
            "foo|bar": {
              "@(2,id)": "&4.&1.&1Id"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "widgets": {
        "*": {
          "@": "&2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Yes, `toLower` makes as exactly you want(I just didn't want to prolong :) )